# How to find a derivative using the quotient rule with a square root in the denominator?

Tags: derivatives

I am trying to solve the assignment below with the quotient rule. Every time I get stuck on a similar assignment which has a square root inside the numerator of a fraction. What do I do with the square root in the numerator and how do I find the derivative?

$$\frac{\sqrt x+3}{x}$$

Comment: Just use $\bigl(\sqrt x\bigr)'$ where required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\sqrt{x}+3}{x}=$

$\frac{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\cdot x-(\sqrt{x}+3)}{x^2}= \frac{\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x}-3}{x^2} = \frac{(\frac{1}{2}-1)\sqrt{x}-3}{x^2} $

$-\frac{\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{x}+3}{x^2}$

because

1. $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x}}=x^{1-\frac{1}{2}}=\sqrt{x}$
2. $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{f}{g}=\frac{f’g-g’f}{g^2}$ and $\frac{d}{dx}x^\alpha=\alpha x^{\alpha-1}$ for every $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$
3. $\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{x}= \frac{d}{dx} x^{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{1}{2}x^{\frac{1}{2}-1}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$

Comment: On the second and third step, how did you merge the square root from both terms?

Comment: what do you think? Other question?

Comment: Hmm, my weakness lies in the simplification. I can't see how I can simplify: 1/2*sqrt(x) - sqrt(x) - 3

Comment: Now I think it is more clear

Comment: Thank you! It is now. I didn't see that I could subtract from the 1/2. I thought it was not allowed to subtract from a product. For example = 6*5-3, I can't just subtract 3 from 6 or 5. But I see now how it is possible in this situation. Many thanks to you!

Answer (score 1):

The fraction rule says that
$$
\left(\frac{\sqrt x + 3}{x}\right)' = \frac{(\sqrt x + 3)'\cdot x - (\sqrt x + 3)\cdot (x)'}{x^2}
$$
Now we need to find the different derivatives in the numerator. The second one is easy: $(x)' = 1$. For the first derivative, $(\sqrt x + 3)'$, you use several rules. First differentiation of sum:
$$
(\sqrt x + 3)' = (\sqrt x)' + (3)'
$$
Then, separately, differentiation of square root, and differentiation of a constant:
$$
(\sqrt x)' + (3)' = \frac1{2\sqrt x} + 0
$$
This we now insert into our original fraction:
$$
\frac{(\sqrt x + 3)'\cdot x - (\sqrt x + 3)\cdot (x)'}{x^2} = \frac{\frac{1}{2\sqrt x}\cdot x - (\sqrt x + 3)\cdot 1}{x^2}
$$
and with that we're done with the differentiation. The rest is algebraic simplification, and then you're finished.